# change this reference to vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, this, debouncing

I would like to have access to a vue instance in an external function (debounce). however this directs to the window object. How can i change the context?
At the moment this is pointing to the object "window" however I would like to get to vue "data"

This is my example

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nbz4hd5o)

```js
var debounce = function(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    media: 'phone'
  },
  methods: {
   resizeMedia: debounce((e) => {
          console.log('resize debounce');
              
          //here vue this?
                this.media = window
                .getComputedStyle(
                document.querySelector('#app'), ':before')
                               .getPropertyValue('content')
                               .replace(/\"/g, '');
                
    },250),
  },
  mounted: function () {
      window.addEventListener('resize',  this.resizeMedia)
  },
  beforeDestroy: function () {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', this.resizeMedia)
  },
})
```

```css
body {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
}
body:before {
      content: "small-phone";
}
@media (min-width: 200px) {
    body:before {
      content: "phone";
    }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
    body:before {
      content: "tablet";
    }
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
    body:before {
      content: "desktop";
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  {{ media }}
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to use your debounce function within vue instance, please? that what your question?

Comment: i would like to change "this.media" variable inside debounce. Debounce shows other context then Vue instance

Comment: you all control of your page with vue instance, so for that a advice you to use debounce within watch, with that you  can achieve your porpose, because within vue instance you have access to window because it's global

Comment: so what should I watch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution would be, to use a "normal" function instead of an arrow function, like this:

```
resizeMedia: debounce(function() {
  // logs the vue instance
  console.log(this);               
 }, 250),
},
```

Comment: Jesus, that's obvious... :-/  I tried a little bit and I understood that it can be done like this: `window.addEventListener('resize',  debounce(this.resizeMedia, 250))`. Thank you for help :-)

Comment: can't believe I've fallen to "this" trap in vue multiple times now, F